# ASP.Net MVC Controller Actions that return void

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If I have the following controller action...

```
public void DoSomething()
{
}
```

will the framework actually convert it to this?

```
public EmptyResult DoSomething()
{
  return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Yes

> A controller that returns void will produce an EmptyResult.

Taken from

[The Life And Times of an ASP.NET MVC Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695917.aspx)

Comment: OK, so it's using a Null Object Pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Seems so, check the [source code of ControllerActionInvoker.cs](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/23011#266452). I haven't verified it, but logic tells me that a void return will set actionReturnValue to null, so an EmptyResult is generated. This is the most recent source code, haven't checked the source for ASP.net MVC 1.0.

```
protected virtual ActionResult CreateActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, object actionReturnValue) {
    if (actionReturnValue == null) {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    ActionResult actionResult = (actionReturnValue as ActionResult) ??
        new ContentResult { Content = Convert.ToString(actionReturnValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) };
    return actionResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't "convert" it, but the two would have the same effect as far as the user is concern. A request would be sent, but no response would come back to the client.

Personally, I think you need to send some response back to the client, even if you just write a continue or success directly to the response stream. Even a JSON `true`, or an empty XML document is better than nothing at all.

Comment: Why the downvotes here? Countered in the name of reason; very good point about always returning something.

Comment: I suspect the reason for the downvote (I didn't) is because a response "does" come back. A 200 OK response. The response body is empty, though. I think with ajax operations it is reasonable to use HTTP status codes to communicate operation results. 200 OK, 500 Error, 403 forbidden, etc. A body isn't always necessary.