# Cannot redirect action to action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Have looked at all the posts on here and none of them are fixing my issue.

I Hit the URL: /Users/KickOutUser

```
public void KickOutUser()
        {
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "You need to be logged in to access that content";
            //Redirect to Login
            RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        /*user controller*/
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            //E.G ErrorMessage comes from HandleUnauthenticatedUser 
            ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = TempData["ErrorMessage"] ?? null;
            return View();
        }
```

With debugging, I can see it hit the first method, then redirect, but the redirect call never calls the Login method, and I end up with a blank view..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void KickOutUser()
```

This method is not returning anything, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048643/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-void)

So in this case, what you can do is return `ActionResult` or better `ViewResult` like as shown below,

```
    public ActionResult KickOutUser()
    {
        TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "You need to be logged in to access that content";
        //Redirect to Login
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to return RedirectToAction from an action method (that has an ActionResult return type).  Calling RedirectToAction by itself will not do anything.

This is not how you should be handling security, though.  You should instead be using an AuthorizationFilter to control access.