# Get request from controller action method doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http

I have a view with a link which is suppose to fire a get request:

```
<span style="margin-right: 20px;">@Html.Hyperlink("http://localhost:59536" + pr.Url, pr.Name)</span>

<span style="margin-right: 20px;">@Html.ActionLink(pr.Name, "LoginExternal", new { url = pr.Url, state = pr.State })</span>
```

When I use custom html helper generating a hyperlink in the view everything works fine. If I use a second method which calls action method in the controller get request is never released:

```
    public async Task LoginExternal(string url, string state)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(uri) };
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
```

What am I missing in the controller action method

Comment: I guess because you are not returning ActionResult !

Comment: That's not the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048643/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-void

Comment: What markup does the 2 helpers produce? Do they differ from each other?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov first span has a direct link to the API method - <a href="http://localhost:59536/api/Account/ExternalLogin">Google</a> while the second calls the method in controller - <a href="/Account/LoginExternal">Google</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are attempting to generate a link to a Web API method using Html.ActionLink. You could use the Html.RouteLink and specify the `httproute=""` value:

```
@Html.RouteLink(
    pr.Name, 
    "DefaultApi", 
    new { 
        httproute = "", 
        controller = "LoginExternal", 
        url = pr.Url, 
        state = pr.State
    }
)
```

You might need to adjust the name of the route if `DefaultApi` is not the Web API route you have.

Comment: Yes, I do think this will be the best solution. Thanks