# MVC Redirect from void-POST Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

My current action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddMessage([FromBody] ShoutboxMessage input)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input.Message) && Request.Cookies["usrid"] != null)
    {
        input.SbUserId = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["usrid"]);
        input.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        context.ShoutboxMessages.Add(input);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I would like to just do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddMessage([FromBody] ShoutboxMessage input)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["usrid"] == null)
        RedirectToAction("Login");

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input.Message))
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

but that doesn't work, obviously. Is there a way to redirect from an action that's supposed to return void? Or, the other way around, can an Action that's supposed to return an `ActionResult` not result in any redirection or reload of the current page?

Edit: the "duplicate" has nothing to do with this. it may be that a `void` action returns basically the same as an `EmptyResult` action, but that's not the topic here, basically I want to know how to chose between an `EmptyResult` and an `ActionResult` at runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC Controller Actions that return void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048643/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-void)

Comment: `EmptyResult` is preferable to `void `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? You can always return `EmptyResult()` from Action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMessage([FromBody] ShoutboxMessage input)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["usrid"] == null)
        return this.RedirectToAction("Login");

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input.Message))
    {
        //...
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't just return null since it will result in a 500 response (even when setting `Response.StatusCode` to 200) and mess up my JS response handling

Comment: Strange, i have edited my answer based on link that mjwills posted in comment. In my test project i am receiving regular empty 200 response.